# How to display random button in main activity among many Buttons?

Tags: android, android-button

I am trying to make 2 different view for user that is one for recommendation i.e (to show one single button) and another for just all information. I need the app to call a random button among all the other button every time i restart the app.

Comment: ``button.setVisibility(View.GONE);`` and ``button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`` with your random logic

Comment: Can you please show your code as a [mcve]? Please [edit] accordingly

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, what is better is to have a single button and every time you restart the app you pick a random behaviour for that button.

There are several ways to do it this is just one:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String BUTTON_TEXT1 = "Button 1";
    private static final String BUTTON_TEXT2 = "Button 2";

    private static final String TEXTVIEW_TEXT1 = "Text to display #1";
    private static final String TEXTVIEW_TEXT2 = "Text to display #2";

    private String[] mButtonTexts = {BUTTON_TEXT1, BUTTON_TEXT2};
    private String[] mTextViewTexts = {TEXTVIEW_TEXT1, TEXTVIEW_TEXT2};

    private static final int NUM_OF_TEXT = 2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        final TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

        Random random = new Random();
        final int index = random.nextInt(NUM_OF_TEXT);

        button.setText(mButtonTexts[index]);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                textView.setText(mTextViewTexts[index]);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per @MarkPazon suggestion

**1. Assign a Button(the random One )**

**2.   Declare a function callRandom()**

**3.   invoke the function callRandom()  from Onclick event of the Random
    Button**

```
 public void callRandom(){
      //Generate Random Numbers
            final int min = 0;
            final int max = n;  //n-no of random events
            Random g=new Random();
            final int random = g.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
     //Random number 0(inclusive)-9(inclusive)

     switch(random){
    case 1:
         //Function 1 break;
    case 2:
         //Function 2 break;
    case 3:
         //Function 3 break;
  case n:
           //Function n break;

      }

    }
```

PS: Here The function calls a Random event on every Button Click.If You Wish to assign random function at the Time of App Starts then paste this with in Oncreate

```
//Generate Random Numbers
                final int min = 0;
                final int max = n;  //n-no of random events
                Random g=new Random();
                final int random = g.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
         //Random number 0(inclusive)-9(inclusive)
```